# How to implement printing to a specific printer from Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, winjs

After following some guidelines in [a Microsoft white paper about implementing printing functionality in apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/br259129), I have some WinJS code that enables me to retrieve an enumeration of all connected print devices to a Windows 8 machine.  My question is if I have this information, is it possible invoke a print contract with a specific printer without brining up the UI for selecting a printer.

Here is the code for enumerating the connect printers:

```
logDevices: function () {

        // This is the GUID for printers
        var printerInterfaceClass="{0ecef634-6ef0-472a-8085-5ad023ecbccd}";
        var selector="System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"" + printerInterfaceClass + "\"";

        // By default, findAllAsync does not return the containerId 
        // for the device it queries.
        // We have to add it as an additonal property to retrieve.
        var containerIdField = "System.Devices.ContainerId";
        var propertiesToRetrieve = [containerIdField];

        // Asynchronously find all printer devices.
        Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(selector, propertiesToRetrieve)
            .done(function (devInfoCollection) {

                console.log("\n[DEV DASH] :   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                devInfoCollection.forEach(function (deviceInfo) {

                    console.log("[DEV DASH] :   Printer : " + deviceInfo['name']);
                    console.log("[DEV DASH] :   ID      : " + deviceInfo['id']);
                    console.log("[DEV DASH] :   Enabled : " + deviceInfo['isEnabled']);
                    console.log("[DEV DASH] :   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ");

                });
                console.log("[DEV DASH] :   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


            }, function (e) {

                console.log("[DEV DASH] : Error in obtaining device information: " + e.message);

            });

    }
```

I am using the following code to bring up the UI that allows a user to select a print device, but is there any way to implement the selection of a printer programmatically with WinJS?

```
Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.showPrintUIAsync();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's a ghost town in Windows 8 land?

Comment: Any luck? I'm looking to do something similar.

Comment: None.  And no representative from Microsoft has attempted to answer here.  I suppose I could hop onto MSDN forums, but eh. . .

Comment: Alright. I have a mail into a guy I know at MS. We'll see if anything pans out.

Comment: Don't you think it's kind of a stretch to have to know somebody as MS to get an answer?  I mean seriously, if MS wants to get devs on board using Javascript / HTML5 / CSS it's going to be more than just the language folks code with.  It's also about community, and an open one at that.

Comment: Yup! I asked "can I bypass printer selection and print to default printer?" Answer = no. I asked "Can I get the printer details back after the user selected a printer to ensure it is an allowed printer type (ie don't want to allow printing to pdf)?" Answer = no.

Comment: I'm talking further with him as he's a project manager with the print services team and we're hoping to get some additional options that may help onto their roadmap. Keep praying!

Comment: Of course if you don't need this app to pass certification, you can do a dllimport of winspool.drv. I got that working :)

Comment: @earthling please explain the dllimport business.  That sounds like it wasn't intended for devs working with WinJS.  But unfortunately, the project I am on requires that it pass certification.